# CSS columns not stacking elements correctly when elements are not divided exactly between columns

Tags: css, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

For some reason if the elements are not divided exactly between columns, they get broken off in weird way.

See the visual representation here:[image]

CSS of root div

```
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
 column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
float: none;
width: 100%;
```

CSS of elements

```
width: 100%;
height: 206px;
```

Solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210244/css-columns-not-stacking-correctly) did not work for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to reset display to childs to avoid to see them spreading into different columns:

```css
.root {
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 206px;
  background: turquoise;
  display: inline-block;/* here layout reset , should do the trick in most browser, feed back appreciated :)*/
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding display: inline-block solved the problem, tnx. NOTE for people who stumble into this problem, make sure that the child elements have float: none as well as inline-block.